# MVC Controller Action only receiving nulls from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ajax call that passes data for two parameters to a controller action. The action is called, but the parameters for the action always have null values (in this case the integer is its default of value of 0). I have made sure to check the packets sent by the ajax call and I do see the correct values I intend to send with the correct parameter/attribute names in stringified JSON.

Here is the Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Summary(int courseID, String test)
{
    using (LearningCurveContext db = new LearningCurveContext())
    {
        Course course = db.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseId == courseID).FirstOrDefault();
        CourseSummary courseSummary = new CourseSummary
        {
            courseID = course.CourseId,
            courseName = course.Name,
            courseDescription = course.Description
        };

        return PartialView(courseSummary);
    }
}
```

Here is the Ajax call:

```
$(document).on("click", ".courseName", function ()
    {
        var element = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: $(element).attr("data-url"),
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "courseID": "1", "test": "blah" }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                $("#details-live").html(data);
            },
            error: function ()
            {
                alert("Could not load course summary");
            }
        });
    });
```

I have tried removing the content type option, as well as not stringifying the data and sending the value of courseID as 1 as well as "1". Nothing seems to work. The URL is correct as the action is being called and the code is run -- just the data doesn't seem to be bound.

Comment: The code you have shown would be throwing a `500 (internal Server Error)` because you have specified `dataType: "json",` but that method returns html. What is the element with `class="courseName"` that you handling (is it a submit button)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It does not throw a 500 error as it never gets to the return (it fails to query the database as nothing exists with an id of 0). The element is an anchor, but the element shouldn't matter as the only data gained from it is the URL which is correct.

Comment: Yes it does matter if its an `<a>` element. Show the relevant view code. (and it will be throwing the error in the browser console despite what you think)

Comment: Try removing the `JSON.stringify` in data attribute. just pass `data: { "courseID": "1", "test": "blah" }`

Comment: @MuhammedShevilKP As stated at the bottom of the post, I have tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Because for Asp.Net core you have to be explicit about where the framework looks for the data. In this case you would need to specify `[FromBody]`, but you would also have to refactor the code to use a model as you can only use that attribute once in the action.

```
public class CourseSummaryPostModel {
    public int courseID { get; set; }
    public String test { get; set; }
}
```

Action update

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Summary([FromBody] CourseSummaryPostModel model) {        
    int courseID = model.courseID;
    String test = model.test;
    using (LearningCurveContext db = new LearningCurveContext()) {
        Course course = db.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseId == courseID).FirstOrDefault();
        CourseSummary courseSummary = new CourseSummary {
            courseID = course.CourseId,
            courseName = course.Name,
            courseDescription = course.Description
        };
        return PartialView(courseSummary);
    }
}
```

The Ajax remains that same as in the original post with the `JSON.stringify`

Reference [Asp.Net Core: Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".courseName", function ()
{
  var element = this;
  $.post( $(element).attr("data-url"),{ courseID: "1", test: "blah" }, function( data ) {
    $("#details-live").html(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET Framework. In core actions only bind a single object as a parameter, and does not like primitive types for binding either. My solution was to put the data I needed to pass into a single model object (rather than as multiple parameters).